# How to handle memory issues for large datasets when the database API doesn't support streaming?

Tags: streaming

I'm working on exposing data through REST in our application framework and need to deal with the case where potentially millions of objects can be queried without limits/offsets. The database API does not support streaming and this won't change in the near future. What would be the best way to deal with a situation like this?

So far I have a few options:

- Implement our own batching mechanism. So from the outside the client just requests everything we have, but internally we do batching with limits and offsets. We do have unique identifiers so we can use those for sorting.

  - A downside is a small risk of data corruption. Our framework supports self-references so for example someone would retrieve all objects of type Person. Person id 500 refers to Person id 1500. Batch 1-1000 is retrieved with person 500 referring to person 1500. This data is streamed away. Then person with id 1500 is deleted and the reference for person with id 500 is updated. Batch 1001-2000 is retrieved but person 1500 is missing. The data for person 500 is already streamed away and the data is now invalid even within one stream.
- Set a maximum amount of objects that are retrieved and let the client deal with batching, including scenario's dealing with the aforementioned data corruption.
- Do nothing and just let applications go out of memory. Leave it up to the developer using the platform to not expose large tables, most definitely not to anonymous users.

I'm hoping to hear some alternatives for this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did more research and do not think there is a proper solution for this. In the end we did manage to get the required changes in the database layer to be able to stream the data. Everything else would have had downsides that are too important.